# Batch FOR loop processing drops equal and comma characters

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

Any batch experts able to explain the following behavior?

I am trying to have a variable which contains the permissions required to be used by a net share command. The variable's name is %GRANT%

I have found that I cannot simply enter "net share ShareName=D:\Path %GRANT%"

However, it does appear that the following will work possibly:

"FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo net share ShareName="D:\Path" %GRANT%') do (%%A)

Here is the issue. The FOR loop described above is NOT working. But it is not working because "it just wont' work." It is not working, because the FOR loop is dropping the comma and equal characters out of the command.

Please see the attached screenshot. You can see that %GRANT% does indeed contain a comma (1.). You can also see that the "IN" command contains an equal sign as should be present in net share. however, when I echo the resulting command in order to troubleshoot what's going on, I see that the FOR loop processing is dropping both the equal and comma characters out of the result (2.).

Can anyone explain this and is there something I can do to make it leave those characters in?

[image: Shreenshot]

Comment: okay, I found my hacked answer, but if anyone has input as to the above behavior, I'm still interested in hearing it.
 
I changed my FOR loop to the following, which provides the desired result.
 
**for /l %A in (1,1,1) do (net share test02="D:\Test Shares\test02" %GRANT%)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "grant=/grant:Everyone^,FULL^=testing"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo net share ShareName="D:\Path" %GRANT%') do (ECHO %%A)
SET "grant=/grant:Everyone,FULL=testing"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ("net share ShareName="D:\Path" %GRANT%") do (ECHO %%A)
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's two slightly different ways to do what you appear to want to do.

The problem is that commas, semicolons, tabs and often `=` are seen as separators. Usng the caret or "quoting the string" overcomes the problem.

Comment: Thanks Magoo!
 
I tested and it definitely worked for getting the equal sign to remain in.
 
The %GRANT% variable on the other hand, did not fare as well.  I tried double-careting its comma so that it would enter the FOR loop with the required comma careted out, but it still got dropped.
 
In any case, I believe I now understand the root issue.  Due to the issue with getting %GRANT% to pass in correctly, I will probably stick with the solution I found by using FOR /L instead.

Comment: I'd try triple-careting. The first caret escapes the second and the third the symbol to be escaped, so an escaped-symbol should be delivered.

Comment: @Magoo, your 2nd `for /F` loop treats the `net` commad line as a literal string because of the surrounding `""`...

Comment: @aschipfl: Certainly. The object of the exercise appears to be to preserve the commas and `=` in the metavariable. `FOR %%A in ("net share ShareName="D:\Path" %GRANT%") do (ECHO %%~A)` would also work (avoiding /f and its options.) If applied to the first form, the carets would be preserved, so the value in the metavariable would contain escaped-[,=] which might be used as say subroutine parameters.